# Phonegap 2.9.1(cordova) Error initializing cordova : class not found message showing up in Android

Tags: android, cordova

Why am I getting this error?

Error initializing cordova : class not found...

Created new project using create.bat
I used cordova-3.3.0-src and imported that project and go to properties and android...
set it as a library.

And in my project I added that cordova-android in my library.

I can't find any reason why this error keep popping up.

Please help me with this.

I installed phonegap 2.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things that you may need to check:

First, make sure you add the correct JS and JAR file. For example, if you are using Cordova-2.9.0 version, you need to use the same version JS file in your project.

Make sure the files that you are adding belong to the same platform.

Make sure you do not rename any system related files. For example, config.xml or other related files.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.Here's how o solved it

1.create a new folder named 'xml' in the res directory of the project.
2. copy the /lib/android/framework/res/xml's config.xml to the project's xml folder.

Then the popup error was gone.